# Supplier login when using spree-drop-ship

Tags: e-commerce, spree, marketplace

I'm working on a marketplace website. The idea is to allow for suppliers to login, add their products, view orders, generate reports etc.

I'm using Spree Commerce, and I see everyone suggesting to use spree-drop-ship extension to achieve all/part of above.(it's not really clear from the documentation, all the features that spree-drop-ship is supposed to add)

I've followed 'demo' instructions from https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship and successfully installed spree with the dropship extension, I can see 'suppliers' tab in /admin page. BUT I don't understand how the suppliers are supposed to login. They don't appear to be special user(actually I can't see in Users any supplier), and also when creating new supplier there is no way to set a password.

So my question is, how are supplier supposed to login, i.e. how they/I create supplier user and set password.

Thank you in advance,
 - Jack

Note:
I know there is also 'marketplace' extension, which is not maintained anymore by @JDutil, but from what I understand it was solving payment issues to the dropshipper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you just need to signup as normal user then from admin panel, from suppliers tab admin can assign a user as supplier. Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: please take a look at Paarth's answer, I'm experiencing same issue, maybe you know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is still in progress, Please see the following steps.

1. Register a normal User
2. From Admin, Add a new supplier. Add the user created above in the user field in new supplier form.
3. Login as a normal user, using the user from step 1.
4. It logs in as a normal user.
5. Now, goto /admin and it will show you supplier admin panel. But, Not able to add a product from here. It shows "Authorization error" when we click on "Add new" link.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I don't think it's still in progress, at least from what I've read.. I'm experiencing the same issue, but I don't event have "Add new" link, I've manually played with the url. Did you try opening an issue at Github ?

Comment: After login using Admin, you have to go to "Suppliers" tab. Then you should be able to create a new supplier. Creating an issue does not make sure we would get it, instead better to create an extension for our purpose.

Comment: I too cannot add products as a supplier.